# Minimal surfaces, but 1 dimension lower

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, minimal-surfaces

There is a set of points. For simplicity, let's say that those are 2D points (although the problem works in more dimensions as well). The goal is to find the minimum possible length of a connected 1-dimensional curve, such that it passes through all the points.

Intuitively, the curve will consist of straight lines, but how do those lines look?

To make things clear, here is an approximation for a solution for a square:

```
.     .
 \   / 
  ---  
 /   \ 
.     .
```

For an equilateral triangle, we would pick a point inside and connect all vertices to it. We can find the best point with some differential equations.

The problem is not that hard to solve for these generic shapes, but is there a way to efficiently solve it for any set of points?

I find this very similar to minimal surfaces, the only difference is that these aren't surfaces, but rather curves.

Comment: My first idea is to draw a complete graph between all points, and add edge weights according to the pairwise distances. Then run an algorithm which calculates the minimal spanning thee of the graph. This is probably not optimal, but it's likely close-to optimal.

Comment: I think it's at worst $2$ times the minimal value in $2$ dimensions anyway. I drew up some triangles and used the triangle inequality, but I wouldn't be able to give you a full proof.

Comment: Yeah, that's actually how I thought of this problem, I was thinking about applications of such algorithm (MST for connecting points on a plane), and I figured that often if we deal with points in space, it's naive to represent it as a graph(for example imagine that points are cities and we are making roads. if we want to minimize the road distance, the MST isn't the best solution.)

Comment: This is called the Steiner tree problem; the PDE/minimal surface aspect of it (minimizers are unions of line segments with endpoints at triple junctions) is well-understood, but there indeed is a nontrivial combinatorial aspect as well.